# Proving that the measure of a set is 0

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We recently talked about Lebesgue measures in our Real Analysis course, and I am badly stuck on the following problem:

> Prove that the set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; |x|+|y| = q \space or \space max\{ |x|, |y|\}= r;q,r \in\mathbb{Q} \}$ has measure $0$

I understand that the basic way of proving some set has a measure 0, is to find an enumerable cover $\{U_i :i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ by closed or open rectangles such that $\sum^{\infty}_{i = i} vol(U_i) <\epsilon\space, \forall\epsilon > 0$.

However I am having trouble not only getting a 'feel' for choosing the right covering but imagining a superset which is easier to work with. The example we did at the lecture was showing that rationals have Lebesgue measure zero. However I am somehow struggling to apply the solution to other problems of the same kind.

Any help is much appreciated, perhaps someone can suggest simpler problems of this kind that I can solve to better understanding.

Comment: Do you know the fact that countable union of measure 0 set has measure 0?

Comment: @pisco125 Yes, so I must show that the set is a countable union of measure 0 sets?